# Getting distinct subsequences of a string equal to a particular string via recursion

Tags: java

**Code logic**

In order to find all subsequences of **String** **s** that are equal to **String** **t**, I made a recursive method **getSub**() to get all the subsequences of input string s and added it to the list. Now I loop through the list (in **numDistinct** method) and try to see all those subsequences in the **list** that matches the **string** **t**. In case there is a match **count** should be incremented and later returned.

**BUT**

**Question**

In the following code count never increases, which means the **if** condition (in **numDistinct** method) does not work as it was intended. Why **t** which is a **string** and **list.get(i)** which should also return a **string** doesn't seem to work with equals method?

```
public static int numDistinct(String s, String t) {

    int count = 0;

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    getSub(s, list);
    StdOut.println(list);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {


        if (t.equals(list.get(i))) {

            count++;

        }
    }
    return count;

}

private static int getSub(String s, ArrayList<String> list) {

    if (s.length() == 0) {

        list.add(" ");
        return 1;
    }

    int smallOutput = getSub(s.substring(1), list);

    char[] cha = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < smallOutput; i++) {

        list.add(cha[0] + list.get(i));
    }

    return 2 * smallOutput;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "rabbbit";
    String t = "rabbit";
    StdOut.println(numDistinct(s, t));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are creating the strings in the list ensures there is a space character at the end of each string. As such, none of them are equal to t.

```
if (s.length() == 0) {

    list.add(""); // remove the space from this line
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out @HopeyOne, " " was getting added to each item in list and i was unable to see it in compiler. Great!